# Adding a Directory to subversion

Tags: svn

I want to add a directory to subversion.My folder structure is given below

```
ParentFolder

    DeviceFolder1---->File1
    DeviceFolder2----->File2
```

**DeviceFolder2** is under the subversion `https://SubversionURL/DeviceFolder2`.I want to add **DeviceFolder1** to subversion `https://SubversionURL/DeviceFolder1`.Here both

**ParentFolder** and **DeviceFolder1** are not under subversion and `https://SubversionURL/DeviceFolder1` doesn't exist. What are the steps that I should follow while adding **DeviceFolder1** to subversion

Note:
I couldn't perform svn add because the parent directory is not a subversion directory.DeviceFolder2 is a checked out directory under subversion `https://SubversionURL/DeviceFolder2` but DeviceFolder1 is a folder created in the local machine and I want  to add it to subversion url `https://SubversionURL/DeviceFolder1`.

Thanks

Comment: Can you use `subprocess` or do you want a Python API?

Comment: no i want the svn command for adding a directory to subversion. A command like svn add

Comment: Are you using SVN 1.7 or earlier? This matters, since in previous SVN versions where metadata was stored per folder, it was possible to attach a working copy under parent working copy, but in 1.7 this is no longer possible.

Comment: then your question has nothing to do with Python.  You are simply asking for SVN commands.  Can you fix your question and retag it accordingly?

Comment: To use svn add, you need to be in a source controlled folder. Since you aren't, you can't just add it. Svn would have no idea where to add it to. You should consider creating your DeviceFolder1 on the server first and follow the steps detailed in Rachel Sanders' answer below.

Comment: As an end result, do you want ParentFolder to be a working copy as well? I.e. do you just want to add DeviceFolder1 to SVN or do you also want DeviceFolder1 and DeviceFolder2 to be under same working copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this helps you, but many SVN commands can be run directly on the SVN server. For example, this will make a new directory:

```
svn mkdir https://SubversionURL/DeviceFolder1 -m "making a new folder"
```

You could then use svn import to import existing files to this directory. Something like this (doublecheck the syntax, haven't done this in a while):

```
svn import DeviceFolder1 https://SubversionURL/DeviceFolder1 -m "importing stuff"
```

One trap: If you want your *local* DeviceFolder1 to be an SVN working copy after you've imported stuff, you'll need to delete your existing directory and check out a new working copy. SVN won't let you check out to a non-empty directory, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if  you have any issues with this but I'd just use  `os.system('svn add *')` or whatever you'd normally run from the command line to add this to SVN.

Comment: i couldn't perform svn add because the parent directory is not a subversion directory.DeviceFolder2 is a checkedout directory but DeviceFolder1 is a folder created in the local machine and i want it to add to subversion url 'https://SubversionURL/DeviceFolder1'